# Использование свойств через названия и итерация по ним

Tags: c#, архитектура

У меня есть клас и у него разные свойства. Есть некоторый набор свойств(настройки, settings), с которыми внутри класса нужно обращаться по названию, а извне нужно проходить по циклу и для каждой из настроек что-то делать, например всем присвоить значение (все настройки однотипные).

Логично сделать отдельное поле класса, массив в котором будут содержаться настройки, но тогда нужно для каждого свойства-настройки прописывать в set, что нужно поменять и массив. А при изменении массива как-то одновременно менять нужное свойство. Мне кажеться должно быть какое-то изящное решение.

Заранее спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, вам не должно быть нужно такое. C# — не Javascript и не PHP, в нём подобные вещи делаются иначе.

То, что вам нужно — словарь `Dictionary<string, T>`, где `T` — общий тип ваших свойств.

Чтение/запись по имени достигается при помощи индексирования (`dict["x"] = dict["y"]`), проверка на наличие свойства по имени — через `ContainsKey` или `TryGetValue`.

Для получения набора всех названий свойств можно использовать `dict.Keys`, но для итерации по всем свойствам проще наверное

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    var key = kvp.Key;
    var value = kvp.Value;
    // ...
}
```

---

Если охота всё же подучать доступ по имени изнутри класса, пойдёт, например, вот такая конструкция:

```
class C
{
    public enum Names { X, Y, Width, Height }
    public static ReadOnlyCollection<Names> AllNames =
        new ReadOnlyCollection<Names>(((Names[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Names))));

    Dictionary<Names, int> Dict = new Dictionary<Names, int>();

    public int this[Names name]
    {
        get => Dict[name];
        set => Dict[name] = value;
    }
}
```

Тут к элементам можно обращаться как `c[C.Names.X] = 1;`. Можно выставить и свойства:

```
    public int X
    {
        get => Dict[Names.X];
        set => Dict[Names.X] = value;
    }


    public int Y
    {
        get => Dict[Names.Y];
        set => Dict[Names.Y] = value;
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get => Dict[Names.Width];
        set => Dict[Names.Width] = value;
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get => Dict[Names.Height];
        set => Dict[Names.Height] = value;
    }
```

но это, как мне кажется, слишком много ручной работы.

---

Кстати, итерацию по словарю можно упростить до

```
foreach (var (key, value) in dict)
{
    // ...
}
```

если определить вспомогательный метод расширения

```
static public class Extensions
{
    static public void Deconstruct<K, V>(this KeyValuePair<K, V> self, out K key, out V value)
    {
        key = self.Key;
        value = self.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пробовал так делать, но много раз используются строковые литералы, что вроде-как направильно, да и неудобно. И да, такое желание появилось после работы с JavaScript-ом) Там мне понравился подход.

Comment: Если у меня есть и Dictionary и отдельные свойства, нужно еще реализовать одновременное изменение одного при изменении другого. Сейчас у меня реализовано так: при переборе пользуюсь словарем, а когда свойство нужно, то беру его так:
private int n => (int)Settings["PointCount"].Value;
Может быть это параноя, но меня смущает что каждый раз осуществляется поиск по словарю (при очень больших циклах будет неплохо так затармаживать) + строковые литералы

Comment: @Rusl: Дополнил ответ ещё одним вариантом. Если боитесь за скорость, замените Dictionary на массив, а enum на индекс в это массиве.

Comment: Спасибо, я так понял абстрактно-идеального решения не существует, но этого достаточно)

Comment: @Rusl: Идеальное решение — через рефлексию, но оно медленное.

Comment: У Dictionary нет метода HasKey, надо использовать ContainsKey

Comment: @Андрей: Точно! Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще рассмотреть вариант сбора всех свойств из класса, чтобы не использовать словарик.

Пример, где все значения свойств сбрасываются в значения по умолчанию:

```
class ASettings : Settings {
    public long LongPropery { get; set; }
}

class BSettings : Settings {
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
}

abstract class Settings {
    public Settings() {
        properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
    }

    readonly PropertyDescriptorCollection properties;

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties() {
        return properties;
    }
}

var aSettings = new ASettings {
    LongPropery = 123L
};
foreach(PropertyDescriptor aSetting in aSettings.GetProperties()) {
    var value = aSetting.PropertyType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(aSetting.PropertyType) : null;
    aSetting.SetValue(aSettings, value);
}
var bSettings = new BSettings {
    IntProperty = 5,
    StringProperty = "Test"
};
foreach(PropertyDescriptor bSetting in bSettings.GetProperties()) {
    var value = bSetting.PropertyType.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(bSetting.PropertyType) : null;
    bSetting.SetValue(bSettings, value);
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно выделить или как то пометить лишь некоторые свойства